# Updating one entry of a sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting

Suppose I have a sorted `std::vector<int>` called `v`. I increase the value of `v[i]` and I want to re-sort the vector. Suppose I expect to increase `v[i]` only by a little bit. The following is certainly wrong.

```
// (WRONG)
int x = v[i]; // the new v[i], that is
v.erase(v.begin() + i);
v.insert(
    std::upper_bound(v.begin() + i, v.end(), x),
    x
);
```

It's wrong because I'm moving almost the whole array back when I delete, and forward when I insert, and I might only be increasing `v[i]` by a little bit, which only requires moving a few entries. Another thought might be:

```
int x = v[i]; // the new v[i], that is
if (/* new v[i] is > old v[i] */) {
    size_t j = i + 1;
    while (v[j] < x && j < v.size()) {
        std::swap(v[j-1], v[j])
        j++;
    }
}
```

and similarly if I've decreased `v[i]` instead of increased it. Is this the best?

Assume I don't have access to `boost::flat_set`. (Not sure if it could do this easily or not.) Apologies if this has been answered; a search didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) to move the element to its new position.  If you really think it won’t move far, it might be faster to search linearly for the new position (or apply a hybrid approach by checking at doubling distances from the old position to find a bound for the `upper_bound`).

Answer (score 2):

You should not `erase` and then `insert` elements when you dont need to. If you increment element at iterator `pos` then you only need to find the place to insert and rotate the elements by one:

```
 auto new_pos = std::lower_bound(pos,end,*pos);
 std::rotate(pos,pos+1,new_pos);
```